# Login authentication for react application

Tags: reactjs, django

I am using Django session based auth for my single page app. I am using below APIs for handling the login and logout functionality. I have used the axios for getting the response from these APIs.

**url.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
```

**login.tsx**

```
const authentication = {
    LoggedIn: false,
    onAuthentication(){
      this.LoggedIn= true;
    },
    getLogInStatus(){
      return this.LoggedIn;
    }
  }
  

const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
    return (
        <Route path= {props.path} render={data=>authentication.getLogInStatus()?(
        <props.component {...data}></props.component>):
        (<Redirect to = {{pathname: '/'}}></Redirect>)}> </Route>

    )
  }


class Login extends React.Component <any, any>{
    constructor(props:  any) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            isLoggenIn: false
        }
    }

    changeHandler = (e: any) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    submitHandler = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(this.state)
        axios
            .post('/api/login/', this.state)
            .then(response => {
                if(response.status === 200){
                    authentication.onAuthentication();
                    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
                }
                else if (response.status === 204) {
                    this.props.showError("Username and password do not match");   
                }
                else {
                    this.props.showError("Username does not exists");
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert("Invalid credentials")
                console.log(error)
            })
    }


    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
            // redirect to home if logged in
            return <Redirect to = {{ pathname: "/home" }} />;
          }
          
            const { username, password} = this.state

                return ()
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('csrf/', views.get_csrf, name='api-csrf'),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='api-login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='api-logout'),
    path('session/', views.session_view, name='api-session'),
    path('whoami/', views.whoami_view, name='api-whoami'),
]
```

Now I want to add the login/auth logic in my react app, i.e. if user has session then user should redirect to main page otherwise it should redirected to login page. How can i implement the authentication logic for the same?

**views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.views import APIView


class SessionView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @staticmethod
    def get(request, format=None):
        return JsonResponse({'isAuthenticated': True})


class WhoAmIView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @staticmethod
    def get(request, format=None):
        return JsonResponse({'username': request.user.username})
```

Comment: Please add minimum working example of what you've tried so far. If you need complete answers, kindly refer to docs. https://reactrouter.com/native/example/auth-workflow

Comment: Hi there, i have updated the question with my tried way